# EF Context is not disposing when using Unity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unity-container

I am attempting to implement a repository pattern but am running into difficulties with my context. When start to debug my UI displays as I expect, all data is returned just as it should but when I try to filter the data I get exceptions from EF informing me that "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command..."

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static UnityContainer Container;
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        Container = container;

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<MyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

        container.AddNewExtension<RepositoryModule>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}

public class RepositoryModule : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IBusinessClass>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager()),
            new InjectionFactory(
                c => new BusinessClass 
                    c.Resolve<IRepository<EntityOne>>(),
                    c.Resolve<IRepository<EntityTwo>>());
        );

        Container.RegisterType<IRepository<EntityOne>, RepoOne>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(
                c => new RepoOne(c.Resolve<MyContext>())));

        Container.RegisterType<IRepository<EntityTwo>, RepoTwo>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(
                c => new RepoTwo(c.Resolve<MyContext>())));         
    }
}
```

My repository interface looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{

    IQueryable<T> Query { get; }
    T GetByID(int id);

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

    T Insert(T entity);

    void Update(T entity);

    void Delete(T entity);

    void Save();
}
```

The implementation of the repositories uses an abstract class for the Save and Dispose functionality:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : IDisposable
{    
    protected MyContext context;

    protected BaseRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save changes
    /// </summary>
    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    #region Dispose

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool diposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The actual repositories look like this:

```
public class RepoOne : BaseRepository, IRepository<EntityOne>
{
    public RepoOne(MyContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<EntityOne> Query => context.EntityOne;

    public EntityOne GetByID(int id)
    {
        return context.EntityOne.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EntityOne> GetAll()
    {
        return context.EntityOne.ToList();
    }

    public EntityOne Insert(EntityOne entity)
    {
        return context.EntityOne.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(EntityOne entity)
    {
        var entityOne = context.EntityOne.Find(entity.ID);
    }

    public void Delete(EntityOne entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that my context is not getting disposed but I can't figure out why. Am I missing something or have I completely messed up the architecture here?

[Edit]
The code is working on the first load. It is only when I go back to the repositories to get a filtered subset of data that I am running into the problem.

I have updated the solution to use a simple factory to get the repositories, so the assignments in Unity now look like this:

```
            Container.RegisterType<IRepository<EntityOne>>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(
                c =>
                    RepositoryFactory<EntityOne>.GetRepository(
                        "EntityOne",
                        c.Resolve<MyContext>())));
```

and the factory:

```
public static class RepositoryFactory<T> where T : class 
{
    public static IRepository<T> GetRepository(string entityType,           PollBookMonitorContext context)
    {
        switch (entityType)
        {
            case "EntityOne":
                    return (IRepository<T>) new RepoOne(context);
            case "EntityTwo":
                    return (IRepository<T>) new RepoTwo(context);
            default: return null;
        }
```

@vendettamit: my PerRequestLifetimeManager

```
public class PerRequestLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
{
    private readonly object key = new object();

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(key))
            return HttpContext.Current.Items[key];

        return null;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = newValue;
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is finally working. I just discovered that one of the tables I was query was having a large amount of data being manipulated all day, and as far as I can tell that was causing an adverse effect in the way EF was reading from the DB. Or maybe I fixed the issue when I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't disposing?

Comment: I'm assuming the exception message stating there is already an open datareader associated with the command means the context hasn't been disposed.

Comment: @crunchy that doesn't have to do with disposing... the problem refers to querying data more than one time simultaneously on the same context (maybe two different http requests are getting the same context object?)... the lifetime of the context object is not really important (you could pass without disposing it), the lifetime of the actual query is (specially on multithreaded scenarios). Are you sure your `PerRequestLifetimeManager` implementation is doing what it should?

Comment: @Jcl yes, I realized that it wasn't a disposing problem a little while ago. I'm not exactly sure what's going on now; every time I attempt to run the code I get through the initial load, but the filter then bails on whatever it's doing with no evidence as to why!

Comment: @crunchy since you say you are are implementing your own `PerRequestLiftetimeManager`, couldn't you just make sure that's working as it should?. You may be making (via Ajax or something) several requests from your view, and if those happen simultaneously, you'll get that exception you are seeing. I don't see any kind of filtering in the posted code, so I'm assuming the code is not there... but just logging (or writing to console or something) the start and end of those `ToList()` should give the hint as to why this is happening

Comment: @Jcl Thanks for that advice. I did check what was coming back and, as mentioned above, one of my calls to the DB was attempting to get data from a table that was getting hit very hard from somewhere else. Once I accounted for that everything started running as it should.

Comment: @crunchy a table getting hit should not give that error unless it's the same datareader (i.e., the same `DbContext` for EF) doing those reads simultaneously. If that's the case (and you are not specifically doing any kind of async code), then your `PerRequestLifetimeManager` is not actually giving one instance per request. You should really check that :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is here:

```
private bool disposed = false;

protected virtual void Dispose(bool diposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the if instead of using the global field disposed, use the argument "disposing"

```
 protected virtual void Dispose(bool diposing)
 {
        if (!disposing) return;        
        context.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: This didn't help that I could see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `PerRequestLifetimeManager` requires to register `UnityPerRequestHttpModule`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx),

> For the instance of the registered type to be disposed automatically when the HTTP request completes, make sure to register the UnityPerRequestHttpModule with the web application.

Check UnityConfig.cs make sure it's not registering the module. The module registration should be done in `Unity.Mvc.Activator.cs`. Alternatively you can also try registering the Module in Startup file(OWIN):

`[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(UnityWebActivator), "Start")]`

Comment: I wrote the PerRequestLifetimeManager myself so it shouldn't need registered as I'm "newing" it up in the RegisterComponents method (I think?)

Comment: This class works with the module mentioned. See details https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Unity.Mvc/Src/PerRequestLifetimeManager.cs

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I wrote a custom PerRequestLifetimeManager, so registering the Unity module would have not impact on my code.

Comment: Ohh I see!! Can you share the insights of your custom lifemanager?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
     // Your code.
}
```

Then on your data context, it would implement your dispose:

```
public void Dispose()
{
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
     if(!disposed)
     {
          if(disposing)
          {     
              component.Dispose();
          }
          disposed = true;
     }
}

~DataContext() { Dispose(false); }
```

You could however clean up your architecture a bit, if you truly wanted to.  An approach you could do, would be in this manner:

```
public interface IRepository
{
     // Your method operation.
}

public interface IFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
     // Container factory, to interject between multiple data context.
}

public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
     IRepository Create();
}

public class DataContext : DbContext, IRepository
{
     // Entity Framework and Repository concreete implementation.
}

public class DataContextFactory : IFactory
{
     public IRepository Create()
     {
         return new DataContext();
     }
}
```

Then you would map the factories with Unity, then you would simply call within a method:

```
using(var context = Create())
     return context.List<Model>(....);
```